# jQuery function mapped to an element through its ID works even after changing elements ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop a jQuery function from being called under a specific state.

```
$('#first-page').click(function(event) {
      // some code
      $(event.target).attr("id","no-id");
      // more code
}
```

For that I renamed the element's **id** as shown above. But the function is still getting called anyway. Shouldn't this have stopped?

Comment: If you really want to disable it that way, use the delegated version of `on`. e.g. `$(document).on('click', '#first-page', function(event){...});` This applies the filter after the event is captured at a higher level. If the id changes it will no longer match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't this have stopped?

No, because the handler is directly bound to the element. The selector is only used to *initially* find the element. It's not used when the event occurs, so changing the ID of the element doesn't have any effect on the handler.

Simply [undbind the event handler](https://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('#first-page').click(function handler(event) {
      // some code
      $(this).off(handler);
      // more code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery binds event listeners to the DOM object representing your element, which is at first identified by the supplied selector.

So to remove the onclick event, you should try something like:

```
$('#first-page').unbind('click');
```